# How to copy data efficiently from one schema to another schema table using postgresql - Without column names

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, upsert

I have two schemas and a table in each schema. Table is called "concept". One Schema is "cdm" schema and other is "vocab" schema.

I would like to copy records from "concept" table of "vocab" schema to "concept" table of "cdm" schema based on certain conditions

concept table has a primary key called concept_id and several other non primary columns.

Ex: vocab.concept has 200 records. I would like to copy only records that satisfy a condition like concept_id > 150

Currently the concept table in CDM schema (cdm.concept) is filled with 150 records. So, I would like to add/insert the remaining 50 records (which is concept_id > 150)

Can you let me know how can I do this copy or kind of ignore duplicates and copy only new records (ie newly added 50 records)

```
INSERT INTO cdm.concept(concept_id,Name,Age,Info) 
SELECT concept_id,Name,Age,Info 
FROM vocab.concept 
where concept_id > 150;
```

**Questions**

1. Is this above sql correct?
2. Is it the only way because my table might have more than 25 columns and I don't wish to type in column names every time I wish to copy.
3. Please note that table already exists in cdm schema. So, I don't wish to use "Create Table" approach

Comment: If you were using a current version of Postgres (9.1 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/))  you could use `insert on conflict` - as you should upgrade anyway, maybe that's another reason to do it now.

Comment: re 1: yes the syntax is correct (which you can easily find out by running it) re 2: you should always list all columns. And if you put that into a SQL script (or even a function) you don't have to type all 25 columns each time.

Comment: To use insert on conflict, I should list down all my values for all columns. Is there anyway to do the same by copy? Either copy from a table or copy from csv.

Comment: You can't use ON CONFLICT with 9.1 to begin with. But yes, you will need to specify all columns for the INSERT part. As you don't want to update the existing one, you would use `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` (after you upgrade from your unsupported version) which does not require specifying the columns to update. Again: you only need to write those columns **once** if you properly put that into a script or function (typing your question already took longer than typing those 25 column names - or letting them insert by your SQL client)

Comment: If you can write as an answer, I can mark it as solution should you be interested